# MySQL ORDER BY FIELD for months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `months` - this contains all 12 months of the calendar, the IDs correspond to the month number.

I will be running a query to retrieve 2 or 3 sequential months from this table, e.g

- April & May
- June, July, August
- December & January

However I want to ensure that whenever December are January and retrieved, that it retrieves them in that order, and not January - December. Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `months`

WHERE start_date BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>

ORDER BY
    FIELD(id, 12, 1)
```

This works for December & January, but now when I try to retrieve January & February it does those in the wrong order, i.e "February - January" - I'm guessing because we specified `1` in the `ORDER BY` as the last value.

Anybody know the correct way to achieve this? As I mentioned this should also work for 3 months, so for example "November, December, January" and "December, January, February" should all be retrieved in that order.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question is about January and February, but your query relates to December and January!?!

Comment: I think we need a question that's more targeted at the actual problem

Comment: How will you pass the list of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want December first, but the other months in order, then:

```
order by (id = 12) desc, id
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  The `desc` puts the `12`s first.

EDIT:

To handle the more general case, you can use window functions.  Assuming the numbers are consecutive, then the issue is trickier.  This will work for 2 and 3-month spans:

```
order by (case min(id) over () > 1 then id end),
         (case when id > 6 1 else 2 end),
         id
```

I'm reluctant to think about a more general solution based only on months.  After all, you can just use:

```
order by start_date
```

Or, if you have an aggregation query:

```
order by min(start_date)
```

to solve the real problem.

Comment: Thanks man! Sometimes we over-complicate things! The `order by start_date` is all I needed to make this work correctly! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE 
 @monthfrom int = 12,
 @monthto int = 1;

with months as (select 1 m
    union all
    select m+1 from months where m<12)


 select m
 from months
 where m in (@monthfrom,@monthto)
 order by
    case when @monthfrom>@monthto
    then
        m%12
    else    
        m
    end
```

result:

```
12
1
```

Basically in MySQL this can be done the same way:

```
set @from =12;
set @to =1;
with recursive months(m) as (
  select 1 m 
  union all 
  select m+1 from months where m<12)   
select * 
from months 
where m in (@from,@to) 
order by case when @from>@to then m%12 else m end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not "mysql solution" properly :

```
with cte (id, month) AS (
  select id, month from months 
  union all 
  select id, month from months
    ) 
, cte1 (id, month, r) as (select id, month, row_number() over() as r from cte ) 
select * from cte1 
  where id in (12, 1) 
           and r >= 12 order by r limit 2 ;
```